# status table for all entries (even in different dates) in database changing value when all checkboxes are checked

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, time-and-attendance

i was testing for an attendance website, logging attendance on different dates (manually changing the date on my device) i have a status column 1 for present and 0 for absent. when i log an attendance where some are absent, the status column on that date are reflected correctly but when I log an attendance where all are present, the status column values on all dates (including the ones with '0') are all changed to '1'. below is the code for the save

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    
    $studentNo=$_POST['studentNo'];
    $check=$_POST['check'];
    $N = count($studentNo);
    $status = "";

  $qurty=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tblattendance where subject = '$id' and date = '$dateTaken' and status = '1'");
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($qurty);

  if($count > 0){

      $statusMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='margin-right:700px;'>Attendance has been taken for today!<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";

  }else
    {
      for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++)
        {
         $studentNo[$i]; 
            if(isset($check[$i]))
                {
                 $qquery=mysqli_query($conn,"update tblattendance set status='1' where studentNo= '$check[$i]'");

                      if ($qquery) {

                          $statusMsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'  style='margin-right:700px;'>Attendance Taken Successfully!<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          $statusMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='margin-right:700px;'>An error Occurred!</div>";
                      }
                  
                }
          }
      }
}
```

```
$query = "SELECT tblsection.section,tblassignteach.secId,tblclass.className,tblsubject.subject,tblstudents.secId,tblstudents.studentNum,tblstudents.firstName,tblstudents.lastName,tblstudents.mname,tblstudents.sex,tblstudents.classId FROM tblstudents 
                      INNER JOIN tblassignteach ON tblassignteach.secId = tblstudents.secId
                      INNER JOIN tblsection ON tblsection.Id = tblstudents.secId
                      INNER JOIN tblclass ON  tblclass.Id = tblstudents.classId
                      INNER JOIN tblclassarms ON tblclassarms.Id = tblassignteach.classArmId
                      WHERE tblassignteach.subject='$id'";
                      $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                      $num = $rs->num_rows;
                      $sn=0;
                      $status="";
                      if($num > 0)
                      { 
                        while ($rows = $rs->fetch_assoc())
                          {
                             $sn = $sn + 1;
                            echo"
                              <tr>
                                <td><input name='check[]' type='checkbox' value=".$rows['studentNum']." class='form-control'></td>
                                <td>".$sn."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['studentNum']."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['lastName']."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['firstName']."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['mname']."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['sex']."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['className']."</td>
                                <td>".$rows['section']."</td> 
                                <td>".$rows['subject']."</td> 
                              </tr>";
                              echo "<input name='studentNo[]' value=".$rows['studentNum']." type='hidden' class='form-control'>";
                          }
                      }
```

```
 $qurty=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from tblattendance where subject= '$id' and dateTimeTaken = '$dateTaken'");
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($qurty);

        if($count == 0){ 

          $qus=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tblstudents.studentNum,tblassignteach.subject from tblstudents 
          inner join tblassignteach on tblassignteach.secId = tblstudents.secId
          where tblassignteach.subject= '$id'");
          while ($ros = $qus->fetch_assoc())
          {
              $qquery=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into tblattendance(studentNo,subject,sessionTermId,status,dateTimeTaken,timeTaken) 
              VALUES('$ros[studentNum]','$id','$sessionTermId','0', '$dateTaken', '$ttimeTaken')");

          }
```

i'm wondering why all the values in all logged dates in the db are changed to '1' and if there is a way to fix this. if you need anything else, please dont hesitate to let me know and I really appreciate all the help i can get. thank you in advance!

Comment: The `where` clause in your update query uses the value of the `check` form variable and compares it to the `StudentNo` column, but your form uses the value of `admissionNumber`. Is that correct?

Comment: You should read up on Prepared Statements instead of concatenating strings into your queries like that, for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: What does the line `$studentNo[$i];`  do? I'm not familiar with lines of code that just have a variable name on them. What is in `$check` when you display it for debugging? What you expect, or something different?

Comment: Hii thank you i've edited that part about the student no and admissionnumber

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was the lack of dots next to the php variables.

```
$qurty=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tblattendance where subject = '".$id."' and date = '".$dateTaken."' and status = 1");
$qquery=mysqli_query($conn,"update tblattendance set status = 1 where studentNo = '".$check[$i]."'");
$qurty=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from tblattendance where subject= '".$id."' and dateTimeTaken = '".$dateTaken."'");
$qus=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tblstudents.studentNum,tblassignteach.subject from tblstudents 
          inner join tblassignteach on tblassignteach.secId = tblstudents.secId
          where tblassignteach.subject= '".$id."'");
$qquery=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into tblattendance(studentNo,subject,sessionTermId,status,dateTimeTaken,timeTaken) 
              VALUES('".$ros[studentNum]."','".$id."','".$sessionTermId."', 0, '".$dateTaken."', '".$ttimeTaken."')");
```